# Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on Templates Manager

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, upgrade, template-manager, fatal-error

I was asked to work on a recently upgraded Joomla 3.4.1 site from earlier versions of Joomla.

I had to copy the main template and create a new one. But when I went in the template manager -> templates to make the copy, the template manager was broken and the following Fatal error was reported:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on
>   administrator/components/com_templates/views/templates/tmpl/default.php
>   on line 101

What's wrong and how to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, a quick look inside the templates folder of the site, presented me the ugly truth - it seems that whoever did the upgrade, has never considered to clean up the site from old code/extensions/templates that are incompatible with Joomla 3.

So, in the templates folder I found 8 old templates since Joomla 1.5, that were still considered as installed templates in Joomla system.

The solution was to uninstall these old incompatible templates and remove all their folders/files from the templates folder.

Template manager now works!